# Java Tomcat Project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, helios

We can create a Java Tomcat Project in eclipse. As per my knowledge its a Java project with a WAR structure. I have searched a lot on web but did not get any satisfactory answer.

I want to know what is the need of Tomcat Project when Dynamic Web Project is there?
Are they different in project hierarchy only or there is any other difference? 
Is it specific to Apache Tomcat i.e. can't be deployed on any other server like JBoss?

Thanks.

Comment: u mean when when you click on "new project", does it give you any option like "java Tomcat Project" same as "dynamic web project" or "maven project" ? I am bit confused with your question..

Comment: Yes. File -> New Project -> Other -> Tomcat Project                   I am using Eclipse Helios and Tomcat 5.5